# Maxima CAS: How to differentiate w.r.t. an expression?

Tags: derivatives, computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

Is there a way to differentiate with respect to an expression, instead of a single variable in [Maxima CAS](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/)? Here is a toy example, which should give $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}x^2=1$:

```
diff(x^2,x^2);
```

with an error in [wxMaxima 20.06.6](http://wxmaxima-developers.github.io/wxmaxima/)

```
diff: second argument must be a variable; found x^2
```

For clarity, I meant first derivative with respect to an expression of $x$, not a second derivative with respect to $x$ itself. Note that the latter gives $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}x^2=2\ne 1$ and can be easily computed as `diff(x^2,x,2)`

[image]

Comment: @OlegMelnikov: Do you mean diff(x^2,x,2); ? Of course, the result is $2$? You can try it online at http://maxima.cesga.es/index.php?c=tqbml5ttggw1vr2lpas4o&n=1

Comment: @Moo, good question. I meant the first derivative. See additional clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply the chain rule in the CAS

$$\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)}=\frac{\frac{df(x)}{dx}}{\frac{dg(x)}{dx}}$$

Just define $g(x)$ and apply.

Comment: Good observation. I'll mark it as correct. Here is the code for your example: `diff(x^4,x)/diff(x^2,x);` and `diff(x^2,x)/diff(x^2,x);`